# How do I run through a Wordpress loop called from a filter function?

Tags: wp-query, loop, filters, advanced-custom-fields

So I'm trying to populate an Advanced Custom Fields selectbox with a nice complicated array based off some post data. I've been trying to do this by doing a custom query and loop through the returned posts.

Unfortunately, the loop seems to return diddly squat. On my test install, it should be returning 10 posts. However, the `var_dump` in the below statement will return `NULL` 10 times. Setting `get_post($post)` inside the loop will return the first result for every instance.

Weirdly, `var_dump`ing `$hw_selectbox_query` will return a seemingly correct object, so it's definitely an issue with the actual loop itself not defining the `$post` object. I could run a `foreach` loop through the returned query, but that doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

FWIW, the function runs perfectly when placed on a blank front-end page.

```
function populate_selectbox_field( $field ){

    $field['choices'] = array();

    $hw_selectbox_args = array(
        post_type => 'custom_post_type',
        orderby => 'title',
        order => 'ASC',
        posts_per_page => -1
    );

    $hw_selectbox_query = new WP_Query($hw_selectbox_args);

    if ( $hw_selectbox_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $hw_selectbox_query->have_posts() ) : $hw_selectbox_query->the_post();

        var_dump($post);

        $field['choices'][$post->ID] = $post->post_title

        // Do more complicated stuff in real life

    endwhile; endif;

    return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=destination_node', 'populate_destination_node_field');
```

Comment: The location of your `var_dump` is **outside** your custom loop, and therefore, has nothing to do with your custom loop.  Move it just after your comment `\\ Do more complicated stuff` (but before the `endwhile;`) and let us know what you get.

Comment: Sorry, well spotted. Unfortunately, I'd just accidentally put it there when composing the question. It does output NULL when it's actually inside the loop. And probably outside it too.

Comment: And what if you put `the_title();` before / after the var_dump?

Comment: See, that works. Why can't I get at the `$post` object within the loop? I need various bits from it to build my array. I've had a look at the `get_the_title()` source code, but can't quite see what's different. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L102

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify the previous comment - I tried putting  `$post = get_post($post);` within the loop, and it just returned the title for the first result, but 10 times. So, sadly, still no closer.

Comment: Realized what I was missing, built an answer for you.  Let me know if it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a custom query, in order to access the `$post` information, you need to reference `post` as a class variable the custom WP_Query.

Since you constructed the query as:
     `$hw_selectbox_query = new WP_Query($hw_selectbox_args);`

Then you would access the `post` variable of `$hw_selectbox_query`, like so:

```
var_dump($hw_selectbox_query->post);
```

This will give you the information you need / want to build your `$field` array.

Comment: Oh. my. god. I'm an idiot. Thanks so much! That works perfectly. I've done this plenty of times before, and yet I just spent an hour missing something this obvious. Thanks for unmuddling my head!

Comment: No worries.  We all need a second pair of eyes sometimes!